# TXT records causes subdomains not to resolve

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, txt-record

i have the following entries in my nginx.conf, this allows me to go to http://somerandomstuff.domain.ie, which my app_subdomain_handler application then handles, this works ok.

```
upstream app_subdomain_handler {
        server 127.0.0.1:5001;
        keepalive 8;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name *.domain.ie;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://app_subdomain_handler/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.domain.ie;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://app_subdomain_handler/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}
```

my problem is that if i add a dns TXT record, say for test.domain.ie, the app_subdomain_handler never recieves the request. I've checked via tcpdump, using

```
tcpdump port 80 -s 0 -w capture.cap
```

and nginx never sees the request. test.domain.ie returns a Server not found message in the browser.

i use linode for hosting and nameservers, there are multiple TXT records, any ideas? Why does the TXT record cause the subdomain not to resolve?

Comment: What's the domain? What does `dig test.domain.ie` output?

Comment: [https://xbt.ie/](https://xbt.ie/)

id 58177
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
test.xbt.ie. IN TXT
;ANSWER
test.xbt.ie. 21599 IN TXT "oa1:btc recipient_address=test; recipient_name=; tx_description=; "
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL

Comment: I don't see any `A` records for `test.xbt.ie`, which seems like it'd be the cause of your problem. You can have both `A` and `TXT` coexisting for the same domain/subdomain.

Comment: is it correct to say that an A record must exist where a TXT record exists in order for the subdomain to resolve?

Comment: An `A` record is necessary for a domain to resolve to an IP address. `TXT` records have nothing to do with that. Some situations require a `TXT` (like SPF records). Some situations require an `A` (like wanting people to get to a website). You can have `A`, `TXT`, or both. They have different purposes.

Comment: I dont have an A record for this one, http://thishasnoarecord.xbt.ie/ but it resolves ok. 

I do have A records for '', '*', 'mail', and 'www'.

It seems that if I add a TXT record, then that subdomain does not resolve, whereas if the TXT record does not exist, the subdomain resolves ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's how wildcard DNS records work.  A wildcard will only be used *if there are no records of **any** type for the name*, not just if there are no records of the requested type.  This is to ensure that requests for `ANY` records don't behave differently to type-specific requests.

Answer (score 1):

You should use A records (or CNAMEs eventually). TXT records should not help.

The idea would be to have this in your zone file:

```
@ IN A ipaddressofyourwebserver
www IN A ipaddressofyourwebserver
* IN A ipaddressofyourwebserver
```

What is your real domain name, so that we can help?

Comment: https://xbt.ie/

the site explains more, but the TXT records as used as part of some other functionality.